# Turtlebot follower 410c

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm attempting to run the Turtlebot follower demo on the 410c, with an Xtion 3d sensor.
Debian: build #110
Following these instructions: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot2e/blob/master/Software.md
I've installed ROS Kinetic as described here: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Debian
My TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=asus_xtion_pro

Now I'm trying to run the Turtlebot Follower demo: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_follower

Those instructions say to only run this:
$ roslaunch turtlebot_follower follower.launch

Here is the output I'm getting when I do that:

> [ERROR] [1470159262.958298249]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/driver] of type [openni2_camera/OpenNI2DriverNodelet] even after refreshing the cache: **Failed to load library /opt/ros/kinetic/lib//libopenni2_camera_nodelet.so**. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libDummyDevice.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
> [ERROR] [1470159262.981851003]: The error before refreshing the cache was: Failed to load library /opt/ros/kinetic/lib//libopenni2_camera_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libDummyDevice.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
> [FATAL] [1470159263.030328781]: Service call failed!
> [camera/driver-4] process has died [pid 17636, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet load openni2_camera/OpenNI2DriverNodelet camera_nodelet_manager ir:=ir rgb:=rgb depth:=depth depth_registered:=depth_registered rgb/image:=rgb/image_raw depth/image:=depth_registered/image_raw __name:=driver __log:=/home/linaro/.ros/log/461e8134-58d7-11e6-8593-0200825a2290/camera-driver-4.log].
> log file: /home/linaro/.ros/log/461e8134-58d7-11e6-8593-0200825a2290/camera-driver-4*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241020/turtlebot-follower-410c/) by [ncrypticus](https://answers.ros.org/users/27672/ncrypticus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect the most likely reason for this error is that the the package is in the workspace but not built.

I have not tested the xtion pro recently on the 410c but would expect it to work. Failure modes I've seen when using SBC computers are typically issues with kernel drivers mounting the device or inadequate data rates for servicing the USB bus causing connection drops which this does not look like.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ncrypticus](https://answers.ros.org/users/27672/ncrypticus/) on 2016-08-11**:
Thanks for the fast response. When you say "the package" do you mean the libopenni2_camera_nodelet package? And do you have any pointers for how to build that?

I found this link: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/groovy/Source%20Installation
But the equivalent page for kinetic doesn't exist.

**Comment by [ncrypticus](https://answers.ros.org/users/27672/ncrypticus/) on 2016-08-11**:
(Sorry for the delay - I assumed replying to the notification would be enough to post my comment but it wasn't!)